# Understanding INNER JOIN logic

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, inner-join, self-join

I have the following table Exchange Rates Schema:

| name | type | kind | null? | default | primary key | unique key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COUNTRY | VARCHAR(10) | COLUMN | Y |  | N | N |
| RATETYPE | VARCHAR(6) | COLUMN | Y |  | N | N |
| FROMCURRENCY | VARCHAR(3) | COLUMN | Y |  | N | N |
| TOCURRENCY | VARCHAR(3) | COLUMN | Y |  | N | N |
| STARTDATE | VARCHAR(12) | COLUMN | Y |  | N | N |
| RATE | NUMBER(15,7) | COLUMN | Y |  | N | N |

Of which I only want the USD/MTHEND rows, i.e.:

```
SELECT FromCurrency, ToCurrency, Date(StartDate, 'YYYYMMDD') AS StartDate, Rate 
FROM EXCHANGERATES
WHERE DATE(StartDate, 'YYYYMMDD') > CURRENT_DATE - 15000 AND RATETYPE = 'MTHEND' AND ToCurrency = 'USD'
ORDER BY FromCurrency, ToCurrency, StartDate;
```

| FROMCURRENCY | TOCURRENCY | STARTDATE | RATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JPY | USD | 2018-12-01 | 113.4700000 |
| JPY | USD | 2019-03-30 | 0.0090342 |
| JPY | USD | 2019-06-28 | 0.0092721 |
| JPY | USD | 2019-08-02 | 0.0093388 |
| JPY | USD | 2019-08-30 | 0.0093967 |
| JPY | USD | 2019-09-27 | 0.0092729 |
| JPY | USD | 2019-11-01 | 0.0092592 |
| JPY | USD | 2019-11-29 | 0.0091315 |
| JPY | USD | 2019-12-28 | 0.0091174 |
| JPY | USD | 2020-02-01 | 0.0091675 |
| JPY | USD | 2020-02-29 | 0.0091802 |
| JPY | USD | 2020-03-28 | 0.0092157 |
| JPY | USD | 2020-05-02 | 0.0093431 |
| JPY | USD | 2020-05-30 | 0.0093266 |
| JPY | USD | 2020-06-27 | 0.0093361 |
| JPY | USD | 2020-08-01 | 0.0095812 |
| JPY | USD | 2020-08-29 | 0.0094144 |
| JPY | USD | 2020-09-26 | 0.0094966 |
| JPY | USD | 2020-10-31 | 0.0095739 |
| JPY | USD | 2020-11-27 | 0.0096061 |
| JPY | USD | 2020-12-26 | 0.0096525 |
| JPY | USD | 2021-01-30 | 0.0095693 |
| JPY | USD | 2021-02-27 | 0.0094197 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| JPY | USD | 2022-02-26 | 0.0086700 |

But there is no End Date column, hence I have the following query using self INNER JOIN to set the end date:

```
    SELECT
    EX.FromCurrency,
    EX.ToCurrency,
    DATE(EX.StartDate,'YYYYMMDD') AS StartDate, DATE(EX2.EndDate,'YYYYMMDD') AS EndDate,
    EX.Rate    
FROM
    EXCHANGERATES EX
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT
        FromCurrency,
        ToCurrency,
        Max(StartDate) AS StartDate,
        20251231 AS EndDate
    FROM
        EXCHANGERATES
    WHERE
        RateType = 'MTHEND'
    GROUP BY
        Fromcurrency,
        ToCurrency
UNION
    SELECT
        E2.FromCurrency,
        E2.ToCurrency,
        Max(E.StartDate) AS StartDate,
        to_number(to_char(DateAdd(DAY,-1,To_Date(to_char(E2.StartDate),'YYYYMMDD')),'YYYYMMDD')) AS EndDate
    FROM
        EXCHANGERATES E
    INNER JOIN 
EXCHANGERATES E2 ON
        E.StartDate < E2.StartDate
        AND E.RateType = E2.RateType
    WHERE
        E.RateType = 'MTHEND'
    GROUP BY
        E2.FromCurrency,
        E2.ToCurrency,
        E2.StartDate) AS EX2 ON
    EX.FromCurrency = EX2.FromCurrency
    AND EX.ToCurrency = EX2.ToCurrency
    AND EX.StartDate = EX2.StartDate
    AND EX.RateType = 'MTHEND'
WHERE
    Ex.tocurrency = 'USD'
ORDER BY    1,  2,  3;
```

| FROMCURRENCY | TOCURRENCY | STARTDATE | ENDDATE | RATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JPY | USD | 2019-12-28 | 2020-01-31 | 0.0091174 |
| JPY | USD | 2020-05-02 | 2020-05-29 | 0.0093431 |
| JPY | USD | 2020-05-30 | 2020-06-26 | 0.0093266 |
| JPY | USD | 2020-06-27 | 2020-07-31 | 0.0093361 |
| JPY | USD | 2020-08-01 | 2020-08-28 | 0.0095812 |
| JPY | USD | 2020-09-26 | 2020-10-30 | 0.0094966 |
| JPY | USD | 2020-10-31 | 2020-11-26 | 0.0095739 |
| JPY | USD | 2020-12-26 | 2021-01-29 | 0.0096525 |
| JPY | USD | 2021-01-30 | 2021-02-26 | 0.0095693 |
| JPY | USD | 2021-02-27 | 2021-03-26 | 0.0094197 |

Why is the INNER result different to tinazmu's query using LEAD below? The below captures all unique USD/MTHEND rows with proper End Date:

```
SELECT
        FromCurrency,
        ToCurrency,
        DATE(StartDate,'YYYYMMDD') AS StartDate,
        LEAD(DateAdd(DAY, -1, Date(StartDate, 'YYYYMMDD')),1,'2025-12-31') 
            OVER (PARTITION BY FromCurrency, ToCurrency, RateType 
                    ORDER BY StartDate) as EndDate, 
        Rate    
FROM
    EXCHANGERATES
WHERE RateType = 'MTHEND' AND ToCurrency = 'USD'
ORDER BY FromCurrency, ToCurrency, StartDate;
```

| FROMCURRENCY | TOCURRENCY | STARTDATE | ENDDATE | RATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JPY | USD | 2018-12-01 | 2019-03-29 | 113.4700000 |
| JPY | USD | 2019-03-30 | 2019-06-27 | 0.0090342 |
| JPY | USD | 2019-06-28 | 2019-08-01 | 0.0092721 |
| JPY | USD | 2019-08-02 | 2019-08-29 | 0.0093388 |
| JPY | USD | 2019-08-30 | 2019-09-26 | 0.0093967 |
| JPY | USD | 2019-09-27 | 2019-10-31 | 0.0092729 |
| JPY | USD | 2019-11-01 | 2019-11-28 | 0.0092592 |
| JPY | USD | 2019-11-29 | 2019-12-27 | 0.0091315 |
| JPY | USD | 2019-12-28 | 2020-01-31 | 0.0091174 |
| JPY | USD | 2020-02-01 | 2020-02-28 | 0.0091675 |

Comment: Can you confirm the datatype of EXCHANGERATES.STARTDATE? if `DATE` then why would you need `To_Date(to_char(E2.StartDate),'YYYYMMDD')` to convert it to date? It is not some integer value in YYYYMMDD format, is it?

Comment: its VARCHAR. I inherited this query so in the original creator's ExchangeRate table, their StartDate appears to have been a different data type!

Comment: Is it in yyyy-mm-dd format? Or yyyymmdd

Comment: YYYYMMDD in VARCHAR  i.e, 20210101, etc.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers & reflect your research. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show your EXCHANGERATES table, but it seems that it has only one date: StartDate (it should have been called EffectiveDate), and it keeps a row per currency pair and date for which a rate is available. In fact the exchange rates change everyday, except on public holidays, and not much is saved by not keeping the rates for the holidays (by copying the rates from the previous day). One would then run their rate conversion query for day-n by simply saying `ON ... EXCHANGERATES.StartDate=DayN`, and all of the above would be unnecessary.

IF you don't have any control on the underlying EXCHANGERATE table's population regime then you have to find a way to get the rate for DayN, and if that is not available, DayN-1, and so on. If you know that the only missing rates are for the weekends, you could simply join to this table 3 times, all with LEFT JOIN, first with StartDate=DayN, the second with StartDate.DayN-1, etc.. , and picking up the latest one available.

If, on the other hand, there are gaps of unpredictable duration, your problems becomes that of a gaps/island problem, and the query you posted is one way of solving it. There are other ways, not necessarily better, look for SQL gaps and Islands problems, consolidating islands/packing.

I don't know the Snowflake platform, but in SQLServer (or Teradata) this could replace your query:

```
SELECT
        FromCurrency,
        ToCurrency,
        RateType,
        Rate,
        StartDate,
        LEAD(DateAdd(day, -1, StartDate),1,'2025-12-31') 
            OVER (partition by FromCurrency, ToCurrency, RateType 
                    ORDER BY by StartDate) as EndDate
FROM  EXCHANGERATES E
```

Update 28-Feb-2022; based on my understanding of your data, this should work for you as a replacement for your query:

```
SELECT
       FromCurrency,
       ToCurrency,
       DATE(StartDate, 'YYYYMMDD') as StartDate,
       LEAD(DateAdd(day, -1, DATE(StartDate, 'YYYYMMDD')),1,'2025-12-31')
            OVER (PARTITION by FromCurrency, ToCurrency, RateType
                  ORDER BY StartDate) as EndDate,
      Rate
FROM  EXCHANGERATES E
WHERE ToCurrency='USD'
  and RateType='MTHEND'
ORDER BY    1,  2,  3;
```

Can you please check?

**Update 1-Mar-2022:**

The union subquery EX2 simply finds all date intervals for 'Month End Rates':
The 1st Part of the union (with SELECT ... Max(StartDate) AS StartDate, 20251231 AS EndDate) finds the latest StartDate for which a month end rate is available for each combination of From/ToCurrency and calls this valid from StartDate to 2025-12-31, a date in the future. This way, the most recent rate can be used for any date>=max(StartDate)

It then combines (2nd part of UNION) the older records as follows: for each month end rate in the table (E2), it finds the previous rate in the table (E, E.StartDate<E2.StartDate would give all earlier records, but
the MAX(E.StartDate) would give us the latest of them: the previous record. It then subtracts 1 day from the late record (E2.StartDate) and labels it the EndDate, because there is a new rate on E2.StartDate.

The outer query (EX) then gets the rates themselves, combining them with the intervals derived in EX2.

For this to work properly, the join condition in the second part of the UNION must specify the same currencies (otherwise we would find a rate for a different currency as the previous record):

```
        E.StartDate < E2.StartDate
        AND E.RateType = E2.RateType
        AND E.FromCurrency = E2.FromCurrency
        AND E.ToCurrency=E2.ToCurrency
```

Maybe this explains the difference...

Comment: Thanks, that's correct the EXCHANGERATES has only the effective date

Comment: Updated the answer to add a SQL server/Teradata implementation based in windowing function LEAD

Comment: Thank you, why is the output is different?
INNER JOIN: 
|JPY         |USD       |2019-12-28|2020-01-31|0.0091174|
|JPY         |USD       |2020-05-02|2020-05-29|0.0093431|
|JPY         |USD       |2020-05-30|2020-06-26|0.0093266|
|JPY         |USD       |2020-06-27|2020-07-31|0.0093361|

vs LEAD
|JPY         |USD       |2018-12-01|2019-03-29|113.4700000|
|JPY         |USD       |2019-03-30|2019-06-27|0.0090342  |
|JPY         |USD       |2019-06-28|2019-08-01|0.0092721  |
|JPY         |USD       |2019-08-02|2019-08-29|0.0093388  |

Comment: I would need rows from your exchangerates table to understand better. What is the `COUNTRY` for, for example; can you list 15 days' worth? and also show us unique COUNTRY (your table definition has it but the query fragment does not use it) and RATE_TYPEs (your query fragment refer to it, but the table definition does not have it).  Are there other columns? what is the primary key for it?

Comment: I added some rows from Exchange rate. The COUNTRY is not used. The country always matches either the FromCurrency or ToCurrency,
--The RateType IS used, but I didn't add it in the query fragment -- updated the original query.

Comment: I tried initially using DATE but the results appear to e different. I understand your LEAD implementation but actually not the INNER query, it is not covering the gaps... I updated to post the data

Comment: It appears that your EXCHANGERATES table used to have inverse rates prior to a certain date. Check the first row returned by my query where the JPY/USD rate:113.47, but then it reverts to USD/JPY rates 0.0090342. We must know data in this table very well to use it. Can you tell why 113.47 is there? Looking at what is returned as the date-ranges they seem to be continuous, why do you think 'not covering the gaps? are there other rates in between for the same FromCurrency/ToCurrency/RateType and not being returned? can you give us an example? carefully check the dates held in varchar though.

Comment: Thank you, this is my fault. I should have showed you the ExchangeRates section with just USD/MTHEND to correctly show the unique rows. i.e. to your question: are "there other rates in between for the same FromCurrency/ToCurrency/RateType and not being returned?" YES, but not by your query, your query is correct and captures all. I don't understand the INNER query and therefore don't understand why it doesn't capture everything.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, yes it was the join statement condition lacking